# How should I interpret the signatures like "fill[A](n: Int)(elem: ⇒ A)"?

Tags: scala, methods

The [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector%24) of `Vector#fill` looks like:

```
def fill[A](n: Int)(elem: ⇒ A): Vector[A]
n the number of elements contained in the collection.
elem the element computation
returns A collection that contains the results of n evaluations of elem.
```

But this is how I invoke it:

```
Vector.fill[Boolean](5)(true)
```

Where is the `elem`? What does it mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

elems signature in `fill` method (`=> A`) means a `by-name` parameter. It's different from simple `by-value` parametes (like `n: Int` in your example) in that there are not computed when the method is called, but when they are referenced in the method body.

So method fill means that it takes the number of elements in the resulting Vector and fills it with elems of type A, `by-name` is used because you can fill vector, for ex. with object, and if you are using `by-value` parameters, then the resulting vector would contain equal object, but with `by-value` parameter it will paste new object with each cycle.

Implementation:

```
def fill[A](n: Int)(elem: => A): CC[A] = {
  val b = newBuilder[A]
  b.sizeHint(n)
  var i = 0
  while (i < n) {
    b += elem // compute elem and add to the collection
    i += 1
  }
  b.result
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that `by-name` parameter recomputed every time it is referenced in the method's body.

Comment: Once knowing it's by-name parameter the rest part is easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

elem is a function that , when invoked once will produce an instance of type "A" in this case Boolean. So in your case function "true" is invoked 5 times and it returns "true" each time.

"elem" is of type "method which returns an A when called"

also the ()() notation in giving parameters allows you to only give part of the parameters first and then pass  the partially "filled" function on. called currying.

Comment: So anything with type `A` in Scala can be viewed as type `=> A`?

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan It simply means do not compute value now, compute when it is needed. So yes all values, except function, they have slightly different way of doing this

Comment: Markus: Elem is **not** a function. It is a by name parameter. Lai: you are correct, except for the fact that ‛=>A‛ is not an actual type. We could say that the parameter's type here is just ‛A‛ ,but the parameter has the additional property of being passed "by name".

Comment: +1 to @RégisJean-Gilles though I would say that =>A is an actual type.  Any putative conformance to A is due to work by the compiler and the spec. Similarly for passing =>A when ()=>A is expected.

Comment: Let's rephrase it to "first class type" if you will. The fact that you cannot define a type alias for `=>A` should be proof enough (and more important, that you canot have `=>A` as the value of a type parameter). I'd agree that it's hard to be precise on the terminology, and actually the spec says "The type of such a parameter is then the parameterless method type => T", so I guess that my terminology and way to describe it was not really correct either. But it is certainly the easiest way to see it IMHO.

Comment: And then again, the spec also freely mixes the terms "method" and "function" while actually those are clearly different (closely related) things, and conflating the two concepts leads to confusion. So it's not always good to focus too hardly on the exact spec terminolgy.

Comment: Also (and sorry in advance for bumping the conversation) "passing =>A when ()=>A is expected" is not possible. For one thing, you cannot have a value of type `=>A`. Now let's say that you meant passing a parameter decalared as `=>A` to a method expecting a parameter declared as `()=>A`, this won't compile. This is because the actual type of the first parameter is `A`, and `A` is definitely not the same as `()=>A`

Comment: ah i admit i missed the lacking ()